# Using .htaccess to rewrite file path to file name with a query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, query-string, filepath

I'm having an issue with rewriting a file path to a file with a query string

I'm trying to take a url that looks like this:

`https:url.com/products/1_Samsung_Galaxy`

and rewrite the request to my server like this:

`https:url.com/model.php?id=1&title=Samsung_Galaxy`

Here's what my htaccess looks like so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

#rewrite no ending files to .php if file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !products/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/products/([1-9]+)(.*)$ model.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

with the current config, the request is going to a file in the same directory as model.php called products.php, but seemingly in a different directory because some of the script files referenced in products.php with relative paths are throwing errors that the objects they contain do not exist.

Really my main issue is that I don't know apache syntax or how it works and I'm having trouble find a resource where I can learn about apache. The apache docs aren't much help for some reason. If there's a good resource to learn about how to write apache files, I'd love to check it out too.

Comment: FYI, Nothing after `#` in the URL will be sent to the server. The hash `#` sign is used by clients (like the browser). This means that if you call `https://url.com/products/model#_model_title`, the server will only get `https://url.com/products/model`

Comment: Thank you for responding. The # was just a reference to the model number that I intend to put there. The actual file name would be something like 1_samsung_galaxy_a12

Comment: When posting code and you explain the issue, please use real world examples so we know what the input/output actually is.

Comment: Okay, let me edit it really quick

Comment: From the question it is unclear when you want to rewrite to model.php and when to products.php.

Comment: Okay, I've just rewritten the question. I only want to rewrite to model.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite /products/<id><slug> to /model.php/.....
RewriteRule ^/?products/(\d+)(.*)$ /model.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

# rewrite to "...php" if such file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

These rules will work if implemented in the http server's host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that, in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host.

The main differences to your attempt:

- The target paths are written as *absolute* path. This solves the issue with requests getting rewritten to different folders.
- The exception rewriting to /model.php is implemented first, so higher up in the file, since the rules are processed from top to bottom. That saves some conditions.

---

You also mention that you are "not familiar with apache syntax" and have difficulties finding resources to learn this.

I would always recommend the official documentation of the apache modules. They are of excellent quality and come with great examples:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Okay, thank you! is it important that the rules are written in this order?

Comment: I commented on the order of rules in the answer.